# When generating a new component, app.module.ts cannot find the new module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

So I have been having a bit of difficulty with angular 6.  I'll try my best to explain:

I am working on a project that is licensed under MIT license, and it is already a pretty solid base project.  Now that I have it styled the way I want it, I want to generate a new component that I can make into a form that a user can fill out.

So, I open CLI and `ng g c FeeSchedule` and I can see the `fee-schedule` component get made. I would think at this point I should be able to compile and see the running `<p> "fee-schedule works!" message <p>`  if I included it.

Error when building after generating component: seems to be a TS-Lint failure?

> `System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'serve' exited
>   without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests.
>   The error output was: Lint errors found in the listed files.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! project@1.0.0 serve: `ng lint && ng serve "--port" "6685"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0
>   serve script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end
>   of the stream.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String
>   sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String
>   sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)`

Any idea why I am running into issues in generating a new component?

I will include as much code as I can that is relevant:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ROUTES } from "./app.routes";
import { LayoutModule } from "./views/layout/layout.module";
import { FeeScheduleComponent } from './views/fee-schedule/fee-schedule.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent, FeeScheduleComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        LayoutModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my stock fee-schedule component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fee-schedule',
  templateUrl: './fee-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fee-schedule.component.css']
})
export class FeeScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I think its important to mention that even if I remove the app-fee-schedule call in the index.html, the application still fails to run.

Attached is my ts lint config;

```
{
    "extends": [ "tslint:latest" ],
    "rulesDirectory": [ "node_modules/codelyzer" ],
    "rules": {
        "angular-whitespace": [ true, "check-interpolation", "check-pipe", "check-semicolon" ],
        "banana-in-box": true,
        "component-class-suffix": [ true, "Component" ],
        "component-selector": [ true, "element", "app", "kebab-case" ],
        "contextual-life-cycle": true,
        "decorator-not-allowed": true,
        "directive-class-suffix": [ true, "Directive" ],
        "directive-selector": [ true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase" ],
        "import-destructuring-spacing": true,
        "indent": [ true, "tabs", 4 ],
        "max-line-length": false,
        "member-access": [ true, "no-public" ],
        "no-attribute-parameter-decorator": true,
        "no-console": false,
        "no-empty": false,
        "no-forward-ref": true,
        "no-input-rename": true,
        "no-output-named-after-standard-event": true,
        "no-output-on-prefix": true,
        "no-output-rename": true,
        "no-submodule-imports": false,
        "no-unused-css": true,
        "no-var-requires": false,
        "pipe-impure": true,
        "pipe-naming": [ "camelCase", "Pipe" ],
        "templates-no-negated-async": true,
        "trailing-comma": false,
        "use-host-property-decorator": true,
        "use-input-property-decorator": true,
        "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
        "use-output-property-decorator": true,
        "use-pipe-decorator": true,
        "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
        "use-view-encapsulation": true
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1021) to see if your problem is solved.
The problem seems to be with the `ng lint`. Try `ng serve` alone to see if it works correctly

Comment: What exactly are you adding to `index.html`? You don't need to be doing anything in `index.html` when adding a component.

Comment: I will attach my ts lint file to the original post..?  maybe you guys will notice something I have missed?

Comment: @narm to answer that question, even if I don't touch the index.html, it fails just after generating the new component.  I can delete the 3(or 4 if you count the spec file) that are generated and then remove the inport statements from the app.module.ts file and it will build and function again.

Comment: Are you in the project's root folder when you try the ng xxx command? Also, if you run `ng --v` what do you get?

Comment: I am in the Angular projects root?  Like. I have multiple projects, so I run the ng g c Inside the ClientApp folder. (?) I believe that is the root--I believe if you try to run those commands outside the CLI project, it would give you a message saying that the command can only be run inside a CLI project.

also, @DeborahK
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO: The issue was that I was the generation was importing the component by default into the App.module.ts, when I wanted it in a specific component.  My understanding of how App.Module was functioning was incorrect.
Thanks for all the pointers, I guess I just didn't explain my code deeply enough when asking my question.